# how deploy my sites with a GITLAB

Tags: deployment, gitlab

I would like to know if there's possibility of deployment (Website) on a prod server with GIT?

Let me explain:

I have a team who work locally, it working with GIT, we would after completing the development, deploy on a server PREPROD and in a second time, Deploy on PROD server?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Use GitLab CI for it.

Answer (score 7):

You would need, with gitlab, to use a **webhook** (same idea as [with GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks)), in order to trigger a git pull from your prod environment.

See an example of a Gitlab webhook at "[How to setup Gitlab with post-receive hook?](https://serverfault.com/a/463510/783)".

Note: that webhook doesn't have to be in php: you can see more details and a different example in "[Jenkins Gitlab Hook Plugin](https://github.com/elvanja/jenkins-gitlab-hook-plugin)".

Comment: but it always deploys, and is always called even though the build fails.

Comment: @matejkramny then you need to make sure that script tests for the correct completion of the build (like test for the presence of a binary that the build is supposed to produce). And that deployment script should only runs if the test is successful.

Answer (score 0):

My answer from a [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471616/how-to-publish-javadocs-in-gitlab/39595887#39595887) of this question:

> You probably want to use [GitLab Pages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/pages/README.html). The documentation provided is quite detailed, you shouldn't have any problems following it. GitLab Pages is an EE- and Gitlab.com-only feature, though. If you're using GitLab CE, you can use this community solution: [gitlab-ce-pages](https://github.com/YuMS/gitlab-ce-pages).
>
> I have implemented the linked project in my own GitLab instance, and can confirm works as expected. Just follow the instructions on the Github page linked above.