# How to publish javadocs in gitlab?

Tags: javadoc, gitlab

How to publish javadocs in gitlab? So far I have javadocs html pages added to repo but when I try to view them, raw text html source is presented, not the redered html page.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how deploy my sites with a GITLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614873/how-deploy-my-sites-with-a-gitlab)

Comment: @Amadan I dont wont to publish any site, I want to publish javadocs in particular.

Comment: I'd also be interested to see the equivalent for scaladoc

Answer (score 3):

An update for anyone who stumbles on this question.

<del>GitLab CE is [getting GitLab Pages in early 2017](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/12/24/were-bringing-gitlab-pages-to-community-edition/).</del>

<del>The earliest estimated release date is January 22nd with Gitlab version 8.16.</del>

GitLab CE has now had GitLab pages implemented on 2/22/17 in version 8.17.

Comment: GitLab Pages was [added to CE with version 8.17](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/milestones/34), released on 22-Feb-2017 under [issue #14605](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14605).

Comment: Thanks for the update :) Will implement this in my installation asap.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [GitLab Pages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/pages/README.html). The documentation provided is quite detailed, you shouldn't have any problems following it. GitLab Pages is an EE- and Gitlab.com-only feature, though. If you're using GitLab CE, you can use this community solution: [gitlab-ce-pages](https://github.com/YuMS/gitlab-ce-pages).

*Edit:* I have now implemented the linked project in my own GitLab instance, and can confirm works as expected. Just follow the instructions on the [GitLab Pages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/pages/README.html).

Comment: Is this a private instance, or could you provide a link to see your build/CI config?

Comment: I would have shared if it still worked. sadly it doesn't, there were some updates in the meantime and I didn't have the time to look into it. let me know if you find something that works for you, I'll do the same.